# login.live.com Programmatically login via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, automation

I'm trying to sign in to https://login.live.com/ via pure JS (I can't use APIs or even JQuery for some reason):

```
document.querySelector("input[id=i0116]").value = "myemail@live.com";
document.querySelector("input[id=i0118]").value = "mypassword";
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
```

But immediately got an error "Enter a valid email address, phone number, or Skype name". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are 22 `inputs` in that form. Looks like you have to fill some more =))

Comment: @KoshVery , yes, but which ones exactly?

Comment: Who knows... Try to contact Microsoft Support.